# Is it fine to remove all the language files for localizations I don't need in The Witcher 2?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Is it alright to remove `CookedPC/*.w2{strings,speech}`, `CookedPC/user_speech/*` and so on for localizations I don't need? From what I saw this could save me nearly 5 GiB and would therefore offset the installation of REDkit a bit. It's not that I'm short on disk space, but I don't like wasting it either.

What steps are required (e.g. removing the registration for the localizations or using REDkit etc)?

I am using the GOG.com version (The Witcher 2 Enhanced Edition).

Comment: I can only think that this would be fine with most versions, with steam however the checksum might whine and you could be forced to download everything again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer *appears* to be: yes, it's possible.

Here's what I did. I hardlinked all the files into a different directory on the same volume, effectively duplicating the whole folder structure. After that I removed folders and files from the installation folder and tried running the game. The only difference is that the "Options" in the launcher don't show the pruned languages anymore.

For good measure I also launched the game *and* loaded a save game. All appears to work perfectly fine. No hiccups.

For reference: I removed all but the `en` locale.